# ArrayList won't print in console

Tags: java

I have an `Employee` class with one method named `addEmployee` which manipulates an `ArrayList` to add employees. My following code won't print the list on the console screen. I can't find out what's wrong with my code.

```
package com.sib.Tmanager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Employee {
    private String EmpFName;
    private String EmpLName;

    public Employee(String empFName, String empLName) {
        super();
        EmpFName = empFName;
        EmpLName = empLName;
    }
    public String getEmpFName() {
        return EmpFName;
    }
    public void setEmpFName(String empFName) {
        EmpFName = empFName;
    }
    public String getEmpLName() {
        return EmpLName;
    }
    public void setEmpLName(String empLName) {
        EmpLName = empLName;
    }

    public static void addEmployee()
    {
        ArrayList<Employee> Emplist= new ArrayList<Employee>();
    
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in) ;
        
        System.out.println("Enter the Firstname of the employee");
        String Fname= s.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the Lastname of the employee");
        String Lname= s.next();
        
        Employee emp = new Employee(Fname, Lname);
        Emplist.add(emp);
        
        //System.out.println(emp.EmpFName +" "+ emp.EmpLName);
        
        System.out.println(Emplist);
    }

}
```

I tried to change my code by overriding the ToString() method and I still have the same following output.

> Enter employee's Firstname
>
> jason
>
> Enter employee's Lastname
>
> karl
>
> [com.sib.Tmanager.Employee@1a758cb]

Comment: I don't see where you are calling `addEmployee`.

Comment: Also override the `toString()` method in your `Employee` class.

Comment: I am calling the addEmployee method in the main which I did not paste here because there is nothing wrong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Arrays.toString(empList.toArray(new Employee[0]))` or `empList.toString()` in order to print the contents of an `ArrayList`. This will print nicely if you override `toString()` in `Employee`.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be an answer, but a bit of advice about class design.

1. Think about an `Employee` as a physical object.

   - Should an `Employee` have a first name? Yes.
   - Should an `Employee` have a last name? Yes.
   - Should an `Employee` be filled with other `Employyes`? Absolutley not.
2. If the above third point doesn't make sense, what should you do?

   - Create a class called something like `EmployeeList`. Should an `EmplpoyeeList` have `Employees`? Why, of course!
   - The above class is the class you want to have the `Employee` `ArrayList`
   - Also, this is where you want to have the `addEmployee` method, so you can add the `Employee` the `EmployeeList`

Here's a example

```
public class EmployeeList {
    ArrayList<Employee> employees;

    public EmployeeList() {
        employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    }

    public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        employees.add(employee);
    }

    public void printEmployees() {
        for (Employee e : employees) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

So in the `main`, you first will create an `EmployeeList` then add `Employee`s to it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EmployeeList list = new EmployeeList();
    list.addEmployee(new Employee("Jim", "Bo");
    list.addEmployee(new Employee("Foo", "Bar");
    list.addEmployee(new Employee("First", "Last");

    list.printEmployees();
}
```

Note: to get the `Employee` object to print out as String representation, you should override the `toString()` method as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

call AddEmployee() from public static void main()

> System.out.println(Emplist)

you are trying to print Emplist object

you have to iterate the arraylist to show it's content

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the ArrayList in the class fields and initialize it in the Constructor

```
public class Employee {
private String EmpFName;
private String EmpLName;
private ArrayList<Employee> Emplist;
.
.
.
}

public Employee(String empFName, String empLName) {
    super();
ArrayList<Employee> Emplist= new ArrayList<Employee>();
    EmpFName = empFName;
    EmpLName = empLName;
}
```

Now when you need to add you only do :

this.Emplist.add(x);

in the addEmployee method